# Features selection with a lot of dummy variables in R

Tags: machine-learning, r, feature-selection

I am performing features selection on 3849 dummy variable (one-hot encoding) using Boruta algorithm and the algorithm is taking forever to run. Is there a faster way I can perform features selection faster or I only have to reduce my number of dummy variables

Comment: How do you end up with 3849 dummies ? Is that one variable with 3849 levels... ? How many instances do you have ?

Comment: Have you tried clustering to identify similar dummies? What about random forest? More information about the data would be helpful.